# "Unexpected error when launching Internet Explorer..." from cruise control selenium test run

Tags: selenium, cruisecontrol

I am attempting to run my selenium test suite as part of a continues integration process using cruise control.

```
 exec workingdir="projects/AtomWeb/trunk/seleniumTest/bin/debug"
             command="nunit-console"
             args="seleniumTest.dll"/>
```

The problem is I get the following error message.

```
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (NoSuchDriver)
```

However when I run this though the console on the build machine with the following command it works fine.

```
nunit-console seleniumTest.dll
```

Any ideas as to why it wont work as part of the build process?

Comment: I found essentially the same question. See   http://stackoverflow.com/q/7236247/507669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CruiseControl is probably running the Selenium server under a different user than when you run it from the console.  Which means Internet Explorer is using a different user's preferences, which may not be set up correctly.  Because that's what that error message is trying to tell you - your IE setup is incorrect.